# Trying to convert an MP4 to WEBP with ffmpeg with different lossless/compression settings, but getting the same result

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webp

I am trying to convert an MP4 video to WEBP.

I am trying different `-lossless` and `-compression_level` settings (as described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#Options-30)), but all the output videos have identical disk size.

`-lossless` can either be `0` or `1` and `-compression_level` can be from `0` to `6`

For example

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -lossless 1 -compression_level 6 \
  -loop 0 -preset default output_lossless1_comp6.webp
```

and

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -lossless 0 -compression_level 0 \
  -loop 0 -preset default output_lossless0_comp0.webp
```

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 6):

Remove `-preset default`. It is overriding `-lossless 0 -compression_level 0`.
Also consider removing `-vcodec libwebp` and letting ffmpeg automatically choose either libwebp or [libwebp_anim](https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=02cf59f3a6192c95ef1394e21a6f87704194bc21).